# Piping matrix to file/only numbers are piped

Tags: r, file

I have a Matrix which I got through

```
l = cutree (clus,  k = 1:j)
```

which looks about like:

```
bs  1 1 1 1 2
x   1 1 2 2 3
v   1 1 2 2 3
e   1 1 2 2 3
nn  1 1 1 3 4
j   1 2 3 4 5
```

Now, I wanted to write l to a file, using:

```
write(l, file = "datia", ncolumns = 6)
```

However, only the Numbers are piped to the file, not the labels.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the output in table form?  You should be able to use:

```
write.table(l, file = "datia", col.names = T, row.names = T)
```

Comment: that did ideed do the trick, I just wonder why this was necessary. I had an emergency shutdown, ad right before that it worked with write just fine.